# Put a obj file from server into scene Unity

Tags: database, unity-game-engine, server

I have an obj file in a server and i want to download it and import it in my scene by code, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im just beginning in unity, but according to what i have research so far is not possible, what you can do is load your obj in Unity, convert it into an Asset Bundle, upload it to your server, and then download it and instantiate it into your app as required

https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/assetbundles-and-assetbundle-manager

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHOu7EJKgkE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qv7KYpxFQxs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ghb3f6dwU5E

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "objImporter.cs" from [unity wiki](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=ObjImporter) to load an obj file at runtime.

To load the obj from an url use this code :

```
void LoadObjFromUrl(string url){
    //you can do more test here to check if the url correct
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) {
        return;
    }

    StartCoroutine(LoadObjFromUrlCoroutine(url));
}


IEnumerator LoadObjFromUrlCoroutine(string url) {
    Mesh mesh;

        UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest www = UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get(filePath);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        mesh = ObjImporter.Instance.ImportFile(www.downloadHandler.text, true);

    GameObject obj = new GameObject();
    MeshFilter meshFilter = obj.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
    MeshRenderer meshRenderer = obj.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    meshFilter.mesh = mesh;

    //add a BoxCollider to the loaded object
    obj.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();

    //this method will set the scale of the loaded model equale to 1 unity units (like the size of the default unity cube)
    ConvertMeshToUnityScale(obj,1);

}

public void ConvertMeshToUnityScale(GameObject theGameObject, float newSize,string axis="y") {

    Renderer renderer = theGameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();

    float size = renderer.bounds.size.y;
    if (axis.ToLower() == "x") {
        size = renderer.bounds.size.x;
    } else if (axis.ToLower() == "z") {
        size = renderer.bounds.size.z;
    }

    Vector3 rescale = theGameObject.transform.localScale;

    rescale.x = newSize * rescale.x / size;
    rescale.y = newSize * rescale.y / size;
    rescale.z = newSize * rescale.z / size;

    theGameObject.transform.localScale = rescale;

}
```